# Minecraft and Networking

Tags: networking, router, minecraft, wired-networking

I am a college student on a small campus. The school's network is set up like so: one single router with a bunch of different subnets connected to it. A friend and I would like to play Minecraft, and he's on a different subnet than I.

I've seen this [set of instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/280660/allowing-a-friend-to-connect-over-the-internet-to-a-minecraft-server-ive-hosted).

However, since he and I are connected via the same router, is it possible to play minecraft without going to the internet and, therefore, don't have to make a server and go through all that mess? (I'm not sure if the minecraft software even allows this atm?)

Earlier this year we tried to connect via wireless, and I could see his game but I could not connect to it. I have yet to try using a hardline to see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is incredibly simple. Both of you should install Hamachi which is a free software VPN that will allow you to add users to your VPN network and they can communicate with your PC directly via this connection. Hamachi will either work via direct connection between clients, or if this is impossible, it will relay the connections (very similar to how skype works).

https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/

Just use the free version (which I think limits you to 10 clients on your VPN network, but this should be enough for just you and a couple buddies).

It will assign a new IP address for your "Hamachi Network Adapter" and this is the IP address you will use to connect your minecraft.

With this setup, you could be in the next room from each other, or half-way around the world. Hamachi doesn't care and your PC's will appear to be on the same network (virtual private network), and can communicate with no problems. It does not require any ports to be opened on the schools firewalls neither, so no worries there. It just works. And it's free. Hard to beat that.

EDIT: I think you'll want to use the "Mesh Network" type when you set things up. This will allow all clients on your VPN to see eachother.

Comment: I'm reading over some of the reviews, and it doesn't look too great. 

"Speeds aren't that impressive for gaming"

"Subscription is cheap, but in order not to lose the connection they'll convince you to keep upgrading your internet speed."

I'll keep looking through it, though. Thank you for the reference!

Comment: not sure what you are reading... 

It is free, no subscription required. Speeds are as fast as your cable can carry it.

Comment: I used to run a private minecraft server for about 5 friends including myself and we all used hamachi - i had minecraft running from a windows machine (server) and everyone used that hamachi ip address to connect. Never a problem. Hamachi has nothing to do with your local internet speed nor will they say "upgrade your speed". It doesn't make sense in this scenario.

Comment: Over a local network you should be fine, it gets worse when all traffic goes through internet.

Comment: @Kwaio all internet traffic is slower than a local network, unless you are lucky and have a gigabit internet uplink (unlikely). Hamachi does/will not slow down your speed, all it is doing is encrypting and tunneling your traffic. If anything, there will be a smidget of CPU processing overhead, but this is so minimal it's unnoticeable on any "modern" system (modern meaning anything with more than 1 cpu core). Hamachi is the correct way to accomplish exactly what the OP wanted... unless you want to setup your own VPN, but this would require a VPN server or router, plus additional configs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you were able to see each other when you both were on wireless because wireless is probably using the same subnet. You can check this by connecting to the wireless network, and running ipconifg from command prompt (Windows) or ifconifg from terminal (Linux) to see your current IP and subnet mask.

In the router (which you probably don't have access to I'm guessing), there is probably a firewall. If you allow the port you are playing Minecraft on, which I believe is 25565, bidirectionally between your IP address/network and their IP address/network, it should work just fine.

The DMZ set by the router/firewall will most likely not allow traffic between private networks, unless specified.

Comment: No, I don't have access to the router. 

I am halfway through my first networking class, and we just learned about TCP ports this past week. Would you mind explaining how to make the ports bidirectional between the two computers? We have yet to hit that subject (:

Comment: this is the hard way of doing this. see my answer for a fast and easy approach that i've used in real life (similar situation to yours).

Comment: @Becca, basically, a firewall blocks ports from entering and/or exiting the network. For you to be able to connect to another private network, it will have to pass through the router/firewall to get there. If the firewall is blocking that port, you will not be able to exit the private network to get the to other private network. You would just need to know the source IP/network, port, and detonation IP/network. I doubt that your school will allow you to edit the firewall or will edit it for you. When I say bidirectional, you will probably need two rules, or add the IPs to the source and dest.

Comment: And this is impossible since I can't plug in the source and destination TCP/IP into the router configuration in order to bypass the firewall?

Comment: @Becca, You would need access to the firewall/router so that you could add a rule as follows. Source: YourIP/FriendsIP, destination: YourIP/FriendsIP, port:25565. The IPs in that rule can be subed out for networks so you don't have to be pinned down to an IP. Also, the reason why your IP and your friends IP are both in source and destination are to make it bidirectional. I understand that this could be difficult for you since you most likely don't have access to the rule base, but this is how you could do it without third party software if you did have full control over your environment.

Comment: @Becca, (couldn't fit this in  the last comment...) Even if you can't implement this to help you with Minecraft, I would still read through my answer as a learning experience for you since you are learning about this stuff in college per an earlier comment by you. I am a systems administrator for a datacenter and deal with complex networks on a daily basis. Using a third party tool for a work around is great for this scenario, but what if you did have access to the firewall and needed to pass other traffic that was more mission critical? My answer would be the solution.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much!! This was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a good tool called connectivity and this enables you to host your own WI-FI connection through your PC, although you won't be able to go online you can still play minecraft together by using the "Open to LAN" button in a single-player world.

Answer (score -1):

Not having any control over your network, your best bet is to try to create your own server off-campus somewhere or buy some cheap hosting. I've used http://www.mpserv.net/ before, they're pretty cheap with a great control panel and lots of options. You could split the cost and invite friends. Just an idea.

Answer (score -1):

Being on different subnets does not necessarily prevent your friend from connecting to your computer, but it does require the router to forward the traffic appropriately, whereas you normally would be able to communicate directly. Clearly, you do not have access to the router configuration, so there is no way to ensure this, but the gateway is probably set up to do the required routing already. In that case, you will be able to join via 'Direct Connect' (provide LAN IP address), although the hosted game will not be detected automatically, since broadcast messages do not reach hosts on other subnets.

Comment: most schools have subnets segmented so they cannot talk to each other. This will not likely be the best solution. See my answer regarding Hamachi below. Hamachi is the standard way to accomplish what the OP is requesting. Google "hamachi minecraft" and you will get tons of results listing tutorials on how to setup this exact config. The OP is not attempting to do anything "special" here, Hamachi is the accepted standard to "solve" this problem.

Comment: @SnakeDoc: There's nothing 'special' about this solution. You're right, it might not work, depending on the router configuration, but if it does, I would argue there is no problem to be solved here; you just connect.

Comment: I was referring to the OP when saying there's nothing "special" they are trying to do... its a standard problem, one that has standard solutions. For gaming communities, Hamachi is that standard solution. The OP appears to have read some bad/inacurate information regarding Hamachi and therefore is not accepting answers. Hamachi is the standard solution here, its cut and dry. OP, please accept an answer so we can move on. Problem is solved.

Comment: I very strongly recommend against using Hamachi for this. It is certainly not the 'standard solution', but it is a very bad one in my opinion, as it is completely unnecessary and does not meet the question's requirements.

Comment: Have you ever used Hamachi? For gaming? No? It is the "standard solution", there is no way around it. If he is segmented and his network traffic cannot talk to his buddy, then there is NO other FREE way to solve this. Period. Suggesting modifying firewall rules, etc as others have simply is not realistic, this is school controlled gear people. Hamachi doesn't care what firewall is in front of it, what your network speed is, where you are, etc. Hamachi is the ONLY solution here. *Spoken from a gamer. I've been doing this for years, Hamachi is the way to go.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I have used Hamachi, extensively. It's terrible. Too many precious moments have been wasted using it. Though Becca appears to have read some horror stories that are obviously highly inaccurate, I do subscribe to life being too short for Hamachi. It attempts to solve a problem that might not even exist in this scenario to begin with, and even if it does, your claim there is no alternative to Hamachi is unfortunately false; there are dozens.

Comment: I have never once had a problem with hamachi in this use scenario. Nor have any of the technically in-adept people I have had use it specifically for this purpose. It is brain-dead easy to setup, and it just runs in the background. Yes, if you try to use it for transferring huge files, or mission-critical things such as Active Directory traffic or DNS, or anything else, then yes, it fails here. It is designed as a Free private VPN service that is super easy to setup and maintain. It is perfect for gaming when you need a direct connection to another pc.

Comment: Minecraft is not latency sensitive like something as Battlefield or similar. For minecraft, Hamachi is the perfect solution, and it is why on all the minecraft community forums Hamachi is the recommened tool for running your own private multiplayer server. Seriously, google it, or get involved in the minecraft community as I have been. Hamachi has added benefits such as is his buddy or the OP move, hamachi still works. If his buddy goes on vacation and is sitting in an airport, hamachi still works. Hamachi works so long as you have a network connection. It's perfect for this solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7901/discussion-between-marcks-thomas-and-snakedoc)

Comment: Thank you, Marcks. I am curious to see if your idea works. Although I'll have to try it later when my friend gets online.

I have a heard a lot from SnakeDoc(BTW: I'm a girl, not a boy. I'm not sure I've met any boy named Becca ;D) about why Hamachi is great. Why do you call it terrible, Marcks, if the horror stories I found are inaccurate?

Comment: Sorry Becca! Didn't pay any attention to the OP's name! doh!

Comment: I'm not sure I've met a girl named @Becca either, but the name does sound rather feminine. Apologies. :) Among the many reasons I honestly despise Hamachi, the biggest is this: it's 'zero-configuration'. As SnakeDoc has pointed out, that can be convenient and it often is, but if Hamachi doesn't work as expected and in my experience, it frequently does, diagnosing and fixing the problem can be a daunting task, even for the most seasoned network admins. By all means, give it a try, there's little harm in that, but should it not work right away, run like you've never run before.

Comment: @Marcks lol! I think we'll have to agree to disagree on this. I am an avid Hamachi fan ( in case no one noticed ;-P )  -- good fight over this one Marcks.

Comment: Really? Becca is quite a common name here in the states.

Either way, thank you both for your ideas. I think I'll try the simpler version Marcks (I must say, I haven't met anyone with your name either) provides first. Hopefully it will work; I hate downloading more programs on my computer. We'll just have to see, I suppose! Thank you, again!